# Selenium screenshots not visible in Robot Framework HTML log file when executing with pabot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, robotframework

I'm having trouble with Selenium screenshots when using pabot to run my tests. They're simply not visible in the HTML log file as seen in the example below (only a dot is appearing) :

[image]

The HTML log file is looking for a file named Acceptance.Bills.Sbip2 12020.Sbip2 14252.visibilityOfReferenceNumberInBillModification-selenium-screenshot-1.png, but my screenshots aren't saved using this name when executing with pabot.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause, the file system. Some [don't like spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/is-space-not-allowed-in-a-filename), while others [don't like really long file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista). Your file name alone is 112 characters.